# How to have separate slugs per dyno on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am running out of space on heroku slug size, so I was thinking I can solve it by separating a *worker* from the main *web* dyno and have heroku built separate slugs for each dyno. Is this even possible? I found no info on this anywhere, so I could neither prove it can be done, nor prove it wrong. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to split web and worker (if it makes sense) and deploy them differently.

You could also look at reducing the slug following the [Heroku guidelines](https://help.heroku.com/KUFMEES1/my-slug-size-is-too-large-how-can-i-make-it-smaller), or using Docker to containerize the application. Docker images are not limited by the slug max size limit.

Comment: unfortunately I can't make my slug size smaller and I know I can split web and worker, but hot tell heroku to build it as separate slugs? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like the underlying issue you want to solve is slug size, have you attempted either of the following potential solutions?

- Ignore files that don't need to be in the final build using `.slugignore` ([documentation](https://help.heroku.com/KUFMEES1/my-slug-size-is-too-large-how-can-i-make-it-smaller))
- Clear the build cache because sometimes this may take up extra space ([documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#build-cache))
- Create a support ticket asking for an increase in your allowed slug size.

While these may not immediately answer your "how can I split up a slug" question, I feel like they may be easier solutions to solving your slug size issue than hacking around your deployment process, which seems *not fun*.

Comment: reducing slug size the conventional documented way is not an option, because problems are not the same in nature. My problem is I have huge dependencies, so there is nothing else I can do but split the app.